# Botframework webchat | how to get rid of 5 second delay after oAuth prompt

Tags: botframework, web-chat

used Node v16.16.0
Emulator is 4.14.1
Also tested with latest production release [4.16.0]

How to reproduce:
.1 Follow all steps for javascript in [Add authentication to a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp)
.2 Press login and enter your details.
.3 When login is succesfull you will notice that the message activities You are now logged in and the other arrive right away but are rendered only 4 seconds later
.4 In the console you will see the following messages:

```
queueIncomingActivitySaga.js:178 botframework-webchat: Timed out while waiting for activity "60fb1610-b9d3-11ee-9214-55ee94be6ec6" which activity "60fc9cb0-b9d3-11ee-9214-55ee94be6ec6" is replying to. {activity: {…}, replyToId: "60fb1610-b9d3-11ee-9214-55ee94be6ec6"}activity: {type: "message", serviceUrl: "http://localhost:52975", channelId: "emulator", from: {…}, conversation: {…}, …}replyToId: "60fb1610-b9d3-11ee-9214-55ee94be6ec6"_proto_: Object
```

The current behavior results in users clicking on the login button multiple time and expecting the authentication failed.

Not sure if this is a bug or a bad implementation. The fact that  it is reproducable using samples makes me guess it is a bug.

Does someone have a workaround or a solution.

I checked if messages from the bot service in time and they do. The messages that should be shown in the next waterfall step after the oAuth prompt are received by webchat but just not rendered for some reason. I checked this in the emulator.